# Nested generic types in Builder pattern: how to implement and avoid type erasure (ascii tree, pictures)

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns

I've been looking to implement a Builder pattern with many subclasses and found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50715225/4759176) by [@Josemy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5133329/josemy). However, it only has 1 level of subclasses: `Pizza -> SomePizza`. I tried to make use of the builder pattern for a more complex hierarchy only to fail dramatically.

I have the following class hierarchy:

```
                Stuff
              /       \
   Food                     Drink
     |                        |
   Pizza                    Juice
  /     \                   /    \
 |     SicilianPizza       |    OrangeJuice
 |                      AppleJuice
CaliforniaPizza
```

Each class has a field(s) that should be set, some of those fields are obligatory (ob) and must be passed, some are optional (op) and can be set via a builder:

```
Stuff -> double price (op)
  Food -> String mealType (op)
    Pizza -> List<String> toppings (op), int size (ob)
      CaliforniaPizza -> boolean addOlives (op)
      SicilianPizza -> boolean addCheese (op)
  Drink -> double density (ob), double alcoholVolume (op)
    Juice -> String color (op)
      AppleJuice -> String appleColor (op)
      OrangeJuice -> int orangeSize (op)
```

I use builders to build the pizzas and drinks:

**TestStuff.java**:

```
public class TestStuff {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CaliforniaPizza californiaPizze = CaliforniaPizza.builder(2)
                                    .addTopping("Tomatoes").addOlives(true).build();
        SicilianPizza sicilianPizza = SicilianPizza.builder(1)
                                    .addTopping("Bacon").addCheese(false).build();

        AppleJuice appleJuice = AppleJuice.builder(40)
                                    .setPrice(120).setAlcoholVolume(0).setAppleColor("yellow").build();
        OrangeJuice orangeJuice = OrangeJuice.builder(35).setOrangeSize(8).build();
    }
}
```

These are my classes:

**Stuff.java**:

```
public abstract class Stuff {
    protected double price;

    protected Stuff()  {}

    protected abstract class Builder<T extends Builder>  {
        protected abstract Stuff build();
        protected abstract T self();

        public T setPrice(double price)  {
            Stuff.this.price = price;
            return (T) self();
        }
    }
}
```

**Food.java**:

```
public abstract class Food extends Stuff {
    protected String mealType; //breakfast/dinner/etc

    protected Food()  {}

    public abstract class Builder<T extends Builder> extends Stuff.Builder<Builder> {
        protected abstract Food build();
        protected abstract T self();

        public T setMealType(String mealType)  {
            Food.this.mealType = mealType;
            return (T) self();
        }
    }
}
```

**Pizza.java**:

```
public abstract class Pizza extends Food {
    protected List<String> toppings = new ArrayList<>();  //optional
    protected int size;  //obligatory

    protected Pizza(int size)  {this.size = size;}

    public abstract class Builder<T extends Builder> extends Food.Builder<Builder>  {
        public T addTopping(String topping)  {
            toppings.add(topping);
            return (T) self();
        }
    }
}
```

**CaliforniaPizza.java**:

```
public class CaliforniaPizza extends Pizza {
    private boolean addOlives;

    private CaliforniaPizza(int size) {super(size);}

    public static Builder builder(int size)  {return new CaliforniaPizza(size).new Builder();}

    public class Builder extends Pizza.Builder<Builder>  {
        @Override
        public CaliforniaPizza build()  {
            return CaliforniaPizza.this;
        }

        @Override
        public Builder self()  {return this;}

        public Builder addOlives(boolean addOlives)  {
            CaliforniaPizza.this.addOlives = addOlives;
            return this;
        }
    }
}
```

**SicilianPizza.java**:

```
public class SicilianPizza extends Pizza {
    private boolean addCheese;

    private SicilianPizza(int size)  {super(size);}

    public static Builder builder(int size)  {
        return new SicilianPizza(size).new Builder();
    }

    public class Builder extends Pizza.Builder<Builder>  {
        @Override
        public SicilianPizza build()  {return SicilianPizza.this;}

        @Override
        public Builder self()  {return this;}

        public Builder addCheese(boolean addCheese)  {
            SicilianPizza.this.addCheese = addCheese;
            return this;
        }
    }
}
```

**Drink.java**:

```
public abstract class Drink extends Stuff {
    protected double density;
    protected double alcoholVolume;

    protected Drink(double density)  {this.density = density;}

    public abstract class Builder<T extends Builder> extends Stuff.Builder<Builder>  {
        protected abstract Drink build();
        protected abstract T self();

        public T setAlcoholVolume(double alcoholVolume)  {
            Drink.this.alcoholVolume = alcoholVolume;
            return (T) self();
        }
    }
}
```

**Juice.java**:

```
public abstract class Juice extends Drink {
    private String color;

    protected Juice(double density)  {super(density);}

    public abstract class Builder<T extends Builder> extends Drink.Builder<Builder>  {
        public Builder setColor(String color)  {
            Juice.this.color = color;
            return (T) self();
        }
    }
}
```

**AppleJuice.java**:

```
public class AppleJuice extends Juice {
    private String appleColor;

    private AppleJuice(double density)  {super(density);}

    public static Builder builder(double density)  {return new AppleJuice(density).new Builder();}

    public class Builder extends Juice.Builder<Builder>  {
        @Override
        public AppleJuice build()  {
            return AppleJuice.this;
        }

        @Override
        public Builder self()  {
            return this;
        }

        public Builder setAppleColor(String appleColor)  {
            AppleJuice.this.appleColor = appleColor;
            return this;
        }
    }
}
```

**OrangeJuice.java**:

```
public class OrangeJuice extends Juice{
    private int orangeSize;

    private OrangeJuice(double density)  {super(density);}

    public static Builder builder(double density)  {return new OrangeJuice(density).new Builder();}

    public class Builder extends Juice.Builder<Builder>  {
        @Override
        public OrangeJuice build()  {return OrangeJuice.this;}

        @Override
        public Builder self()  {return this;}

        public Builder setOrangeSize(int orangeSize)  {
            OrangeJuice.this.orangeSize = orangeSize;
            return this;
        }
    }
}
```

I have several problems with this code:

1. `@Override` annotations above `build()` and `self` inside `CaliforniaPizza` and `SicilianPizza` are highlighted in Idea Intellij and the error message says that method does not override method from its super class. While there are no such errors inside `Juice` child classes.
2. This line inside `TestStuff`:

```
 AppleJuice appleJuice = AppleJuice.builder(40)                    
      .setPrice(120).setAlcoholVolume(0)
      .setAppleColor("yellow").build();
```

gives error: `setAppleColor` is highlited with red and can't be resolved. The reason is that `setAlcoholVolume` returns a `Drink.Builder` instead of `AppleJuice.Builder`. At the same time if I were to call `setAlcoholVolume` right after `builder()` method it would return `Juice.Builder`:

[image]

3. Although there are problems with juices builders, at least I can somewhat access all the methods (at least if I call them right after `builder()`. However with foods my options are limited:

[image]

There's not Food's `setMealType` there.

4. I have a `return (T) self()` line inside setters in `Juice` and `Pizza`. However, only inside `Juice` do I get the warning about unchecked cast:

[image]

while in `Pizza` I get no warning at all.

I have suspicions that at least problems 2 and 3 have to do with type erasure. An `AppleJuice.Builder` gets passed to `Juice.Builder` as `T`, but then the `Juice.Builder<AppleJuice.Builder>` gets passed to `Drink.Builder<Juice.Builder>` and the information about `AppleJuice` gets lost. Then `Drink.Builder<Juice.Builder>` gets passed to `Stuff.Builder<Drink.Builder>` and only information about `Drink.Builder` is retained. Thus when I call `setPrice(120)` right away, it returns `Drink.Builder` instead of `Juice.Builder`. If I'm correct, what is the way to fix it? And what are the reasons behind another issues I've encountered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The cast**

```
    protected abstract T self();

    public T setPrice(double price)  {
        Stuff.this.price = price;
        return (T) self();
    }
```

`self()` already returns `T`. The cast is unnecessary.

**Unresolved methods**

```
public abstract class Stuff {
   // ...
    protected abstract class Builder<T extends Builder>  {
```

`Builder` is a generic type, but it's used a raw type here. It needs the type parameter, like `java.lang.Enum`.

```
    protected abstract class Builder<T extends Builder<T>>  {
```

Again in subtypes.

```
public abstract class Food extends Stuff {
    // ...

    public abstract class Builder<T extends Builder> extends Stuff.Builder<Builder>
```

Also here we want to parameterise `StuffBuilder` with `T`.

```
    public abstract class Builder<T extends Builder> extends Stuff.Builder<T>
```

**The `@Override`s**

With the types sorted, the override problems should disappear.

**Edit:**

So I've been through and made the changes to the code. (Added `package`, `import` and removed `public` from `class`es to make compilable in one blob.) Eclipse is happy with it, except for the unused variables.

```
package pizza;

import java.util.*;

class TestStuff {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CaliforniaPizza californiaPizze = CaliforniaPizza.builder(2)
                                    .addTopping("Tomatoes").addOlives(true).build();
        SicilianPizza sicilianPizza = SicilianPizza.builder(1)
                                    .addTopping("Bacon").addCheese(false).build();

        AppleJuice appleJuice = AppleJuice.builder(40)
                                    .setPrice(120).setAlcoholVolume(0).setAppleColor("yellow").build();
        OrangeJuice orangeJuice = OrangeJuice.builder(35).setOrangeSize(8).build();
    }
}

abstract class Stuff {
    protected double price;

    protected Stuff()  {}

    protected abstract class Builder<T extends Builder<T>>  {
        protected abstract Stuff build();
        protected abstract T self();

        public T setPrice(double price)  {
            Stuff.this.price = price;
            return self();
        }
    }
}

abstract class Food extends Stuff {
    protected String mealType; //breakfast/dinner/etc

    protected Food()  {}

    public abstract class Builder<T extends Builder<T>> extends Stuff.Builder<T> {
        protected abstract Food build();
        protected abstract T self();

        public T setMealType(String mealType)  {
            Food.this.mealType = mealType;
            return self();
        }
    }
}

abstract class Pizza extends Food {
    protected List<String> toppings = new ArrayList<>();  //optional
    protected int size;  //obligatory

    protected Pizza(int size)  {this.size = size;}

    public abstract class Builder<T extends Builder<T>> extends Food.Builder<T>  {
        public T addTopping(String topping)  {
            toppings.add(topping);
            return self();
        }
    }
}

class CaliforniaPizza extends Pizza {
    private boolean addOlives;

    private CaliforniaPizza(int size) {super(size);}

    public static Builder builder(int size)  {return new CaliforniaPizza(size).new Builder();}

    public class Builder extends Pizza.Builder<Builder>  {
        @Override
        public CaliforniaPizza build()  {
            return CaliforniaPizza.this;
        }

        @Override
        public Builder self()  {return this;}

        public Builder addOlives(boolean addOlives)  {
            CaliforniaPizza.this.addOlives = addOlives;
            return this;
        }
    }
}

class SicilianPizza extends Pizza {
    private boolean addCheese;

    private SicilianPizza(int size)  {super(size);}

    public static Builder builder(int size)  {
        return new SicilianPizza(size).new Builder();
    }

    public class Builder extends Pizza.Builder<Builder>  {
        @Override
        public SicilianPizza build()  {return SicilianPizza.this;}

        @Override
        public Builder self()  {return this;}

        public Builder addCheese(boolean addCheese)  {
            SicilianPizza.this.addCheese = addCheese;
            return this;
        }
    }
}

abstract class Drink extends Stuff {
    protected double density;
    protected double alcoholVolume;

    protected Drink(double density)  {this.density = density;}

    public abstract class Builder<T extends Builder<T>> extends Stuff.Builder<T>  {
        protected abstract Drink build();
        protected abstract T self();

        public T setAlcoholVolume(double alcoholVolume)  {
            Drink.this.alcoholVolume = alcoholVolume;
            return (T) self();
        }
    }
}

abstract class Juice extends Drink {
    private String color;

    protected Juice(double density)  {super(density);}

    public abstract class Builder<T extends Builder<T>> extends Drink.Builder<T>  {
        public Builder<T> setColor(String color)  {
            Juice.this.color = color;
            return self();
        }
    }
}
class AppleJuice extends Juice {
    private String appleColor;

    private AppleJuice(double density)  {super(density);}

    public static Builder builder(double density)  {return new AppleJuice(density).new Builder();}

    public class Builder extends Juice.Builder<Builder>  {
        @Override
        public AppleJuice build()  {
            return AppleJuice.this;
        }

        @Override
        public Builder self()  {
            return this;
        }

        public Builder setAppleColor(String appleColor)  {
            AppleJuice.this.appleColor = appleColor;
            return this;
        }
    }
}

class OrangeJuice extends Juice{
    private int orangeSize;

    private OrangeJuice(double density)  {super(density);}

    public static Builder builder(double density)  {return new OrangeJuice(density).new Builder();}

    public class Builder extends Juice.Builder<Builder>  {
        @Override
        public OrangeJuice build()  {return OrangeJuice.this;}

        @Override
        public Builder self()  {return this;}

        public Builder setOrangeSize(int orangeSize)  {
            OrangeJuice.this.orangeSize = orangeSize;
            return this;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I made it so:
**Stuff**:
`protected abstract class Builder<T extends Builder<T>>  {`
**Food**: `public abstract class Builder<T extends Builder> extends Stuff.Builder<Builder<T>> {` **Drink**: `public abstract class Builder<T extends Builder> extends Stuff.Builder<Builder<T>>  {`, but I still have @Overrides being red in Pizza children

Comment: Making this `public abstract class Builder<T extends Builder> extends Food.Builder<Builder<T>>  {` inside **Pizza** didn't help either

Comment: And putting this `public abstract class Builder<T extends Builder> extends Stuff.Builder<T> {` inside **Food** gives an error on second `T`: `type parameter is not within its bound, should extend Stuff.Builder<T>`

Comment: Also  I tried to put ` public abstract class Builder<T extends Builder<T>> extends Food.Builder<Builder<T>>  {` into Juice, Pizza, Drink and Food. The Overrides in pizza children are still red

Comment: `extends Food.Builder<Builder<T>> ` should be `extends Food.Builder<T>`, etc.

Comment: I've run into another issue with this, though. I'm trying to pass a parent builder to a method to create a parent-type object. I made it a bountied question, would be very grateful for help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58883563/java-builder-classes-generics-hierarchy-how-to-make-build-return-correct-meth